# Efficient way to perform grid search for reduced set of cross-validated data using sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, optimization, scikit-learn, hyperparameter

I am using grid search to find the optimal parameters for 2 models. I have to build one model with entire dataset and another model with reduced dataset (required to keep the folds same for both the models). So in case of second model, a list of datapoints will be omitted/ removed from the same fold which has been used for first model (one with entire dataset). Below is my code:

```
    rkf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=2, n_repeats=5, random_state=24)
    rkf_new_indices = []
    for train_idx, test_idx in rkf.split(x):
        Model1x_train, Model1x_test = x[train_idx], x[test_idx]
        Model1y_train, Model1y_test = y[train_idx], y[test_idx]
        temp_list1 = train_idx.copy()
        temp_list2 = test_idx.copy()
        Model2trn_idx = remove_datapoints(temp_list1, out_list)
        Model2tst_idx = remove_datapoints(temp_list2, out_list)
        Model2train_idx = list(Model2trn_idx)
        Model2test_idx = list(Model2tst_idx)
        rkf_new_indices = np.append(Model2train_idx, Model2test_idx)
    param_grid = [{'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear']}, {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': ['rbf']},]
    svr_model = SVR()
    # define search for model with entire dataset
    BASE_SVR = GridSearchCV(svr_model, param_grid, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', n_jobs=-1, cv=rkf, return_train_score=True)
    BASE_SVR_grid_results = BASE_SVR.fit(x, y)
    # define search for model with reduced dataset
    New_SVR = GridSearchCV(svr_model, param_grid, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', n_jobs=-1, cv=rkf_new_indices, return_train_score=True)
    New_SVR_grid_results = New_SVR.fit(x, y)
```

For second GridSearch, it is not able to form train, test sets with reduced data points. How can I perform GridSearch on reduced dataset while keeping same cross-validation splits?

Comment: This question probably belongs on stackoverflow or datascience.SE